# Плавность появления текста

Tags: html, css

Как установить плавность появления текста через hover без jquery?

```html
<div class='first_block'>
    <div class='second_block'>Текст</div>
</div>
```

```css
.first_block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

.second_block { display: none; }
.first_block:hover .second_block { display: block; }
```

Comment: Посмотрите на свойство css3 animate

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Можно через прозрачность (*opacity*), так как стиль имеет числовое значение от 0 до 1, тоесть имеет промежуточное число с плавающей точкой, например 0.5, а значит к нему можно применить плавный переход (*transition*)

А *display* не имеет промежуточных значений, поэтому *transition* к нему не применим

```css
.first_block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px red solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

.second_block { opacity: 0; transition: .2s; }
.first_block:hover .second_block { opacity: 1; transition: .2s; }
```

```html
<div class='first_block'>
    <div class='second_block'>Текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не стоит забывать про кросс-браузерность (см. мой ответ)

Comment: @ВикторЕвлампьев, сейчас на webkit почти всё и работает. И в хроме `transition` и в опере. ms это у нас IE? На него можно забить. Как с фирефокосм пока не знаю, но там, вродее, тоже работает без `-moz-`. Проверьте кто-нибудь. А также `All` уже никто не пишет, либо ничего, либо `opacity`

Comment: Спасибо  за совет :).

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогает с анимацией в css3 это:

```
webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

Где 0.2s - время анимации

Comment: Уже пробовал, для текста свойство transition не работает. Посмотрю что за css3 animate.

Comment: для префикса `webkit` тоже нужен дефис

Comment: @l1sZ, что значит _для текста не работает_? стоит добавить в вопрос. как именно пытались его использовать